# Asp .Net Identity customize AspNetUser primary id field value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, identity

I want to provide own Primary ID generation logic so that I can provide the value for Primary Id field. 
I know, can change the the type but I want to control the Id creation logic.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: we have existing users in legacy application and want move all users into new app and don't want to change the Id field due lots of dependency on existing primary Id field value.

Comment: Perhaps you can be more specific, because this does not explain why you need to change the Id creation logic. I also wonder what the nature of these dependencies are. Anyways, the only requirement of the Id field is that is has to be unique. So why not move the legacy users (using the original key as Id) and create new users as usual? I don't think there's a chance of duplicates. But I would rather leave the current Id field and logic intact, without further dependencies, and add a field containing the 'old' id. If the value has to be set in a claim then change the logic on token creation.

Comment: Thanks Ruard. I also suggested the same solution to teamto add another field that contain old id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to override Id field

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public override string Id
    {
        get { return base.Id; }
        set { base.Id = value; }
    }
}

var user = new ApplicationUser
{
    Id = "CustomId",
    UserName = "user",
    Email = "user@email.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can almost certainly extend UserManager to override the neccessary functions and have control over this. They provide a `AddUserManager<T>()` registration helper to allow you to easily provide your own implementation when registering ASP.Net Identity.

You can find the source code here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/v3.0.1/src/Identity

Also, there's no hard `identityserver4` requirement to use ASP.Net Identity - if it does not meet your needs then you are free to implement something that does.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the primary key `Id` of your `AspNetUser` to [No value generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#value-generation-patterns), then you could add your custom Id value when you create user.

In your dbcontext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
    }
```

Add migration and update database, then you could generate your own value for primary Id.